# Google Calendar API Freebusy JQuery $.post gets 400 (Bad Request) Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I am new to javascript, JQuery and Google API, so the answer to this question may be a very simple thing that I am overlooking. I've checked all available Google Calendar Freebusy Questions on this site, but I can't manage to make their answers fit my code in any way.

I am trying to write a script for an html page that checks a public calendar's freebusy query. Google says that the HTTP Request should be

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy
```

with a request body of

```
{
  "timeMin": datetime,
  "timeMax": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "groupExpansionMax": integer,
  "calendarExpansionMax": integer,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": string
    }
  ]
}
```

My current html page includes the latest jquery library, and the script I'm writing. Calling the script on the page results in a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` error. A further dig into the error information returns a parse error with `"This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."`

My script looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
  $.GoogleCalendarFreebusy = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
      apiKey: '[projectkey]',
      getID: '[id]@group.calendar.google.com',
      element: '#div'
    };

    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key=' + options.apiKey,
           {"items":[{"id": getID }],"timeMin":"2015-04-10T14:15:00.000Z","timeMax":"2015-04-20T23:30:00.000Z"}, "null", "json")    
    .done(function(data) {
        loaded(data);
      });

    function loaded(data) {
      var status = data.calendars[getID].busy;

      console.log(status);

      if(status.length !== 0 ) {

      for(var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
        var statusEntry = status[i];
        var startTime = statusEntry.start;
        var endTime = statusEntry.end;
      }

        var now = new Date().toISOString();
        var element = options.element ;
        var name = element.substr(1);

        if (now > startTime && now < endTime){

             $(options.element).append( 'Available!');

        }

        else {

            $(options.element).append( 'Unavailable!');

            }

    } else {

    $(options.element).append('Unavailable!');

    }

    }

  };
})(jQuery);
```

My request is receiving the proper response in the [Google Explorer "Try It"](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#tryit), so I think it may be javascript error/json request I'm overlooking? Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: Is the calendar you are looking at public? Otherwise you will need to authenticate.

Comment: The calendar is set to public [share only my free/busy information]. With the calendar settings changed to purely public, I'm still getting a 400 bad request error.

Comment: try putting ' quotes around this: {"items":[{"id":"[id]@group.calendar.google.com"}],"timeMin":"2015-04-10T14:15:00.000Z","timeMax":"2015-04-20T23:30:00.000Z"}

Comment: Unfortunately quotes didn't help either. Updating original post with further error information.

Comment: Post the raw output of the POST body, so we see what's being sent (use Network tab to get it). So we see things like what `datetime` and `string` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Calendar API Post requests need to have the content-type specified as JSON to avoid the above error. Processing the POST as an AJAX request with contentType specified solves this error.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key=' + options.apiKey,
  type: 'POST',
  data: '{"items":[{"id": "[id]@group.calendar.google.com"}], "timeMin": "2015-04-10T14:15:00.000Z", "timeMax": "2015-04-20T23:30:00.000Z"}',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: 'null'
})
```

Thank you for the suggestions!